# Why Pytorch autograd returns 'None' and throws error without variable exponentiated

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I have some strange behavior I do not understand from Pytorch autograd, while trying to compute the second partial derivative with respect to `x`. The code

```
def f(x,y):
   return x**1 
x = torch.tensor([3.0,2.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0,3.0], requires_grad=True)
z = f(x,y)
# differentiate z with respect to x twice
for _ in range(2):
    dx = torch.autograd.grad(z, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x), create_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
    z = dx
print(z)
```

as expected, gives

```
tensor([0., 0.])
```

However, without exponentiating x to 1, and multiplying by `y` as follows

```
def f(x,y):
    return x*y 
x = torch.tensor([3.0,2.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0,3.0], requires_grad=True)
z = f(x,y)
# differentiate z with respect to x twice
for _ in range(2):
    dx = torch.autograd.grad(z, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x), create_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
    z = dx
print(z)
```

we get the output

```
None
```

Worst of all, just having the function return x as follows:

```
def f(x,y):
   return x 
x = torch.tensor([3.0,2.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0,3.0], requires_grad=True)
z = f(x,y)
# differentiate z with respect to x twice
for _ in range(2):
    dx = torch.autograd.grad(z, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x), create_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
    z = dx
print(z)
```

Throws the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[59], line 9
  7 # differentiate z with respect to x twice
  8 for _ in range(2):
----> 9     dx = torch.autograd.grad(z, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x), create_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
 10     z = dx
 11 print(z)

 File ~/miniconda3/envs/randomvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:394, in grad(outputs, inputs, grad_outputs, retain_graph, create_graph, only_inputs, allow_unused, is_grads_batched, materialize_grads)
390     result = _vmap_internals._vmap(vjp, 0, 0, allow_none_pass_through=True)(
391         grad_outputs_
392     )
393 else:
--> 394     result = Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
395         t_outputs,
396         grad_outputs_,
397         retain_graph,
398         create_graph,
399         t_inputs,
400         allow_unused,
401         accumulate_grad=False,
402     )  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
403 if materialize_grads:
404     result = tuple(
405         output
406         if output is not None
407         else torch.zeros_like(input, requires_grad=True)
408         for (output, input) in zip(result, t_inputs)
409     )

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Does anyone understand what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

First, the example

```py
def f(x,y):
   return x
```

Autograd tracks operations performed. Your function only returns the input tensor `x`. Since no operations are performed, there is no gradient to compute. When you compute the first derivative, you get a tensor `[1., 1.]`, which is the gradient of `x` with respect to itself. Since no computations have been performed, the gradient tensor is not part of any computation graph. As a result, the `requires_grad` attribute of the first derivative is zero. When you then try to compute the second derivative, your `z` value is the first derivative tensor which has no grad attribute, raising the error.

Second, the example of

```py
def f(x,y):
    return x*y
```

The first derivative of `z` wrt `x` is `y`. For computational simplicity, `MulBackward` populates the grad tensor with the data/computational graph of `y`. This means the first derivative tensor does not have `x` in it's computational graph. You can verify this by removing the `allow_unused` parameter.

```py
def f(x,y):
    return x*y 
x = torch.tensor([3.0,2.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0,3.0], requires_grad=True)
z = f(x,y)

dx = torch.autograd.grad(z, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x), create_graph=True)[0]
dx2 = torch.autograd.grad(dx, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x))[0]
```

Computing `dx2` will raise the error `One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph`. There is no chain of operations linking `dx` to `x`. As a result, there is no derivative to be computed.

If you try compute the second derivative with a function that retains `x` in the first derivative compute chain, things will work.

```py
def f(x,y):
    return x.pow(y )
x = torch.tensor([3.0,2.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0,3.0], requires_grad=True)
z = f(x,y)

dx = torch.autograd.grad(z, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x), create_graph=True)[0]
dx2 = torch.autograd.grad(dx, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x))[0]
```

Comment: `When you compute the first derivative, you get a tensor [1., 1.], which is the gradient of x with respect to itself.` and `Since no computations have been performed...` sounds contradictory to me. Could you explain further please? Also, is it natural for autograd to not have the ability to differentiate any well defined function? The example I gave is toy just enough to illustrate the point but this gave me strange results in real applications.

Comment: What contradiction do you see? wrt "well defined functions", functions are a human abstraction. Autograd tracks specific operations performed. Autograd backpropages through a computational graph. That can only be done if there is a computational graph to backprop through.

Comment: Computing the first derivative gives `[1.,1.]` , then how is it `Since no computations have been performed...`. To your second point, does it mean autograd does not compute derivatives for constant functions?

Comment: When you say constant function, are you referring to `f(x)=c` or your example of `f(x)=x`? In the first example, there is no computational graph linking the input `x` to the constant output `c`, so you can't compute `dc/dx`. In the second case, there is no operation performed and therefore no computational graph. Wrapping a noop in a python function doesn't change this. Autograd only tracks operations performed. I expect returning a ones tensor with no grad attribute for self-derivatives (`dx/dx`) was added for edge cases.

Comment: Yes, so derivative of a constant function of the form `f(x)=c` is not supported?

Comment: "not supported" is the wrong term as this behavior is expected. To compute `dy/dx` with autograd, you need a computational graph connecting `y` to `x`. For any function where there isn't a computational graph connecting `y` to `x`, you cannot compute `dy/dx`. If this is an issue for your application, you can work around it by computing gradients with `allow_unused=True` and replacing any `None` gradients with `torch.zeros_like(x)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256676/discussion-between-toonia-and-karl).